# JS Global variable is undefined in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
var x = 1;
var o = {
    x: 2,
    y: function () {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
};
setTimeout(o.y, 1000);
```

Node version: 8.1.3

Excute node main.js --->  **undefined**

But get the correct result 1 in Chrome console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the global variable don't use `this`:

```js
var x = 1;
var o = {
    x: 2,
    y: function () {
        console.log(x);
    }
};
setTimeout(function(){o.y()}, 1000);
```

Otherwise use it like this:

```js
var x = 1;
var o = {
    x: 2,
    y: function () {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
};
setTimeout(function(){o.y()}, 1000);
```

Comment: The second result is 2 not 1.

Comment: That's right, because the second example is not getting the global `x` variable. In a web browser in global scope `this` refers to `window`. In node global `this` refers to `global`. When you call `setTimeout` the scope is global. https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = 1;
var o = {
    x: 2,
    y: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
};
setTimeout(o.y, 1000);
```

If you would look at the output of this code when running via node, it would be like

```
Timeout {
  _called: true,
  _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idleStart: 39,
  _onTimeout: [Function: y],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null }
```

As you can this the `this` object in a `Timeout` object and the value `x` is not defined and hence the result `undefined`. `setTimeout` takes the function you want to execute from the main thread and put it in eventLoop to be executed later. What get passed to eventloop is function definition. When executed in the `Timeout` context, it is undefined.

Lets run this program again in the browser console

```
var x = 1;
var o = {
    x: 2,
    y: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
};
setTimeout(o.y, 1000);
```

This time the output would be a `Window` object and we have defined `x` in the window scope and hence the output of `this.x` would be `1` and not `2`.

The right way is already mentioned by [Alexander-Higgins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624988/alexander-higgins).

If you would like to learn more about event loop, I recommend listening to this excellent talk on event loop. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it but this should work. I will run it later.

```
var x = 1;
var o = {
    x: 2,
    y: function () {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
};
setTimeout(function(){o.y()}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks,you lost "()" at o.y

Comment: I tested, the result is 2 not 1